# Use C2DM in Android-x86

Tags: android, api, android-c2dm, android-x86

I use Android-x86 installed in virtual box and communicating with adb to debug my android application.
I know that since it is an open source project, it is not possible to use google API libraries.
But I know that using Maps is possible (somepeople did it), do you know any way to instal cd2m libraries to be able to test push in my emulator ? 
Thxs

Comment: The "somepeople" are pirating Google Maps, apparently, since that is not available for distribution this way.

Comment: I understand. Too bad because debugging with android-x86 in virtual box is so good.

Comment: While I support the idea, I don't think it's legally doable. Google does not, as a matter of policy, open up the relevant bits.

Note that you cannot even associate a Google account with an Android-x86 instance. And having an associated Google account is a documented prerequisite for C2DM to work.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the C2DM framework is dependent in the android market. If your device doesn't contain the android market, it will be difficult to receive the C2DM stuff.